# Appending multiple CSV's in c#

Tags: c#, csv, merge

I am generating multiple CSV's in a folder ,I have to merge all of them and make one file.

P.s.
1.They all will have same headers.
2.Their names are not fixed and will be changed every other day acc to date and some other parameters.

Comment: You will have to write code. The easiest way is to google the code. There are high chances that you will get the exact code you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really tested but should give you an idea:

```
var allCsv = Directory.EnumerateFiles("Src-Path", "*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); //Enumeration of the top directory
string[] header = { File.ReadLines(allCsv.First()).First(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)) };
var mergedData = allCsv
    .SelectMany(csv => File.ReadLines(csv)
        .SkipWhile(l => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).Skip(1));// skip header of each file     
File.WriteAllLines("Dest-Path", header.Concat(mergedData));
```

Note that you have to add `using  System.Linq;`

Comment: Hi,i am using 3.5 framework so unable to use concat and readlines,what else i can use in place of this? p.s. not very much familiar with the c#

Comment: @user3686917: you can use LINQ with .NET 3.5, but you cannot use the overload of `WriteAllLInes` which accepts an `IEnumerable<string>`, you have to use the `string[]`. Therefore use `File.WriteAllLines("Dest-Path", header.Concat(mergedData).ToArray());`

Comment: But you're right, `File.ReadLines` and `Directory.EnumerateFiles` were also new in .NET 4 so you need `File.ReadAllLines` and `Directory.GetFiles` which are less efficient in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: WriteallLines i dont think will create any problem in 3.5,if we use it like      File.WritAllLines("Destpath",header.Concat(mergedData.ToArray())) ,correct me if i m wrong

Comment: @user3686917: no problem, have a look at my second to last comment ;-)

Comment: need your help for this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790667/print-excel-generated-using-spreadsheetgear-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This works but with a minor tweak to use "*.csv" instead of ".*csv" in the search pattern.