# Print excel (generated using Spreadsheetgear) in C#

Tags: c#, excel, printing, spreadsheetgear

In c# i am generating an excel in specific format, i have to print the same excel format on click_print.

P.s.-Microsoft Office not available,using SpreadSheetGear for this.

Comment: GetExcel() - Downloads excel in given format,Now i have to write a new function PrintExcel() on click event,I am not able to figure out any way or any function to do so.To elaborate more,for eg: we have sheet.Printout() method if use Microsoft Office,then how it will be done for SpreadsheetGear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend Chuck's answer if you have a UI and are utilizing the WorkbookView control.  If you are generating this workbook in-code without a UI, you can also print a workbook by using the [WorkbookPrintDocument](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Drawing~SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Printing.WorkbookPrintDocument.html) class.  Below is an example that demonstrates this in a console application:

```
using SpreadsheetGear;
using SpreadsheetGear.Printing;
using SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Printing;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create a workbook with some cell data
    IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveWorksheet;
    IRange cells = worksheet.Cells;
    cells["A1:D10"].Value = "=RAND()";

    // Create a WorkbookPrintDocument.  
    WorkbookPrintDocument printDocument = new WorkbookPrintDocument(worksheet, PrintWhat.Sheet);

    // Set the printer if necessary...let's go old school.
    printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Epson MX-80";

    // Print it
    printDocument.Print();
}
```

If you are using the .NET 4.0 build of SpreadsheetGear 2012, you'll need to add a reference to the SpreadsheetGear2012.Drawing.dll assembly to access the SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Printing namespace.

Also note that I specify to print (the used range of) the sheet via PrintWhat.Sheet.  See the SpreadsheetGear.Printing.[PrintWhat](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Printing.PrintWhat.html) enum for more options.

Answer (score 1):

Spreadsheetgear has a print method for the objects they provide.

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.3.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView~Print.html

This should get you started.